# pdo php multiple queries with select menu

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I made populated selectmenu's to make queries to my sql database. The first option-tags of all select menu's have `value=""` Now everything works fine when I'm using 2 selectmenu's. But If I want to use more (in my case 48) it becomes rather complex. Is there an easier way?

examples of both pages:

```
 <select name="titel" id="titel" value="">
 <option value="">Selecteer</option>
 <?php
 if($rowCount > 0){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        echo '<option  value="'.$row['titel'].'">'.$row['titel'].'</option>';
    }
 }else{
    echo '<option value="">Language not available</option>';
 }
 ?>
 </select>
```

2nd page:

loginscript etc:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Library";

if( (isset($_POST['titel']) && $_POST['titel'] != '') ) {    
$sql .= " where titel =:titel";

if ( (isset($_POST['version']) && $_POST['version'] != '') ) {    
$sql .= " AND version =:version"; 
   }    
 } 

if ( (isset($_POST['version']) && $_POST['version'] != '') && !   (isset($_POST['titel']) && $_POST['titel'] != '') ) {    
$sql .= " where version =:version"; 
 }

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);    

 if( (isset($_POST['titel']) && $_POST['titel'] != '') ) {
 $query->bindParam(':titel', $_POST['titel']);
 }

 if( (isset($_POST['version']) && $_POST['version'] != '') ) {
 $query->bindParam(':version', $_POST['version']);
 }

 $query->execute();
```

Comment: why can't you have a query for each condition instead of appending the where clause only.

Comment: if you only need `AND` operator then you can create an array of conditions and then implode it to the query `if (!empty($conditions) ) { $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $conditions); }`

Comment: Could you gave an example of how it would look like, because I do not exactly know how you mean that?

Comment: @xcx If you asked me for example so first you create the array `$conditions = array(); if( (isset($_POST['titel']) && $_POST['titel'] != '') ) { array_push($conditions, "titel =:titel"); }` and then you use the code in my first comment

Comment: Awesome Alon Eitan, thanks, you're the best..